# CSS not connecting-Help!!!!

Tags: template, css

I am freaking out- as all things I am about to launch our Magento in 2 days. I made some minor changes in the XML files and updated the logo through our FTP. Came back and recached- everything looked great and working...

2 hours later I am updating the social icon links and refresh the cache...Now it looks as if my whole site's template or CSS is missing! Someone please help! I don't know what to do to try to resolve this issue!

http://market.matthewsenvironmentalsolutions.com[image]

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have a 404 in css

If you view source you see

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://market.matthewsenvironmentalsolutions.com/skin/frontend/base/default/css/styles.css" media="all" />
```

Which means magento can't find the styles.css in your theme folder and search it to base, where it can't find it either.

Check local.xml in your theme folder for syntax errors

Check that the files are there

Check your selected package in system, configuration, design

Check permissions and ownership in skin folder.

And then you should be ok.